# How to use conditional Goto in Soap UI?

Tags: soapui

i am working on Soap UI.

How to use conditional Goto in Soap UI?

Is it kind of assertion or if-else way..?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It may help if you supply some code, perhaps showing what you've already tried.

Answer (score 3):

It is kind of "if-else". Conditional goto consists of xpath expressions apllied to response of previous test step. If one of this xpath expressions evaluates to true then execusion transfers to target test step. Here you can read more: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/controlling-flow.html

Comment: 1. Once the flow is redirected towards the target test step, the flow continues in the same path. Right? Ex. if step 1 is a JDBC step, step 2 is conditional goto which redirects to step 4. Then the flow would be 4, 5, 6, ..
2. In case I have two if-else conditions in step 2, Cond. 1 takes flow to 3,4,5,.. and Cond. 2 skips 3 and 4 and straightaway takes it to 5,6,7,... Does that mean that only one condition will run based on the condition. And thus only one flow will be followed. (i.e. either 3,4,5  OR 5,6,7) Right??